# Find Filename with the Largest Number

Tags: bash

I have a folder with 1-4 million files. Each file has this format:

```
trial_nubyb_$i_out.html
```

where $i is a number from 1 onwards

How do I get the largest 5 numbered files in the folder? I just need the 5 largest *numbers*, don't even need the filenames i.e. i just need largest 5 $i and no need trial_nubyb_$i_out.html, but the entire filenames are fine.

If I "ls -la | tail -5" this doesn't work because the system orders the filenames "alphabetically" and not from smallest to largest number, so the last 5 are actually:

```
trial_nubyb_999998_out.html
trial_nubyb_999999_out.html
trial_nubyb_99999_out.html
trial_nubyb_9999_out.html
trial_nubyb_999_out.html
```

I am using bash on Ubuntu.

A simple bash solution, but if it is too completed, PHP also welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This answer applies to `ls` from the [GNU core utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) which is used in Ubuntu. It is not actually included in bash itself and you would e.g. see a different output if you were using macOS.

You can add the [`-v`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/ls.1.html) option to get a *"natural sort of (version) numbers within text"*:

```
ls -lav | tail -5
```

`ls` will then sort "trial_nubyb_10_out.html" *after* "trial_nubyb_9_out.html":

```
bash-4.4$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 1 cg cg 4096 Nov 12 12:16 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 cg cg 4096 Sep 9 10:53 ..
bash-4.4$ touch trial_nubyb_{1,9,10,99,219}_out.html
bash-4.4$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 1 cg cg 4096 Nov 12 12:17 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 cg cg 4096 Sep 9 10:53 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 23941 23941 0 Nov 12 12:17 trial_nubyb_10_out.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 23941 23941 0 Nov 12 12:17 trial_nubyb_1_out.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 23941 23941 0 Nov 12 12:17 trial_nubyb_219_out.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 23941 23941 0 Nov 12 12:17 trial_nubyb_99_out.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 23941 23941 0 Nov 12 12:17 trial_nubyb_9_out.html
bash-4.4$ ls -lav
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 1 cg cg 4096 Nov 12 12:17 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 cg cg 4096 Sep 9 10:53 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 23941 23941 0 Nov 12 12:17 trial_nubyb_1_out.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 23941 23941 0 Nov 12 12:17 trial_nubyb_9_out.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 23941 23941 0 Nov 12 12:17 trial_nubyb_10_out.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 23941 23941 0 Nov 12 12:17 trial_nubyb_99_out.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 23941 23941 0 Nov 12 12:17 trial_nubyb_219_out.html
```

(Note that *version sort* actually has [a bit more complex logic](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html#Details-about-version-sort), but that won't influence your current use case.)

Comment: Nice one! here is an alternative to sort the result in reverse order `ls -1vr | head -5`, `-r` for reverse and `-1` (number one) to print out file names only

Comment: Urm, in macOS, the `ls` man page says: `-v  Force unedited printing of non-graphic characters; this is the default when output is not to a terminal.` You might want to qualify your answer to reflect that you're using `ls` from Coreutils, common on Linux, but not on other operating systems .. and that this solution is not a **[tag:bash]** solution at all, and is not portable. It's always preferable if answers are portable, even if questions are not.

Comment: @ghoti: Good point, I've updated my answer. Feel free to comment again if you still see room for enhancement. I won't change it to be portable, though, as you have already answered yourself.

Comment: Good stuff. My only other thoughts would be that you could streamline your sample file creation with `touch troal_nubyb_{1,9,10,99,219}_out.html`, and the `-a` option for `ls` could be skipped. But those are minor.

Comment: I actually did this first in an online shell that did not support the streamlined version, but you are right. I kept the `-a` option because OP was using it but I added another note on the version sort as it's not just a "simple" natural ordering as one might think.

Answer (score 1):

Bash can't do what you want, easily. While it's possible to *write* sort functions in bash, it includes none of its own, so your best bet is to use other tools to sort.

While the Linux coreutils version of `ls` provides `-v` option that does what you want, it's not portable and won't work in macOS, FreeBSD, Solaris, etc.  A portable option might be the following:

```
ls -f | cut -d_ -f3 | sort -n | tail -5
```

The `-f` option for `ls` tells it not to sort its output at all. If you have FOUR MILLION files in a directory, and you're sorting the output, you probably want this.

`cut` is an easy way to split up a string. We set a delimiter and a list of fields to output.

`sort -n` sorts numerically. This isn't quite the same as the Linux "natural/version" sort from `ls -v`, but it may perform better.  YMMV.

If you want to sort the filenames without splitting the numbers out of them, the `sort` command has provisions for that.  `man sort` and look for `-t` and `-k` options.  These options are portable too.  :)

```
$ ls -lf | sort -t_ -k3n | tail -5
```

(This assumes you don't have any stray underscores before the filename.)